# How to connect a calc sheet using pyodbc interface

Tags: pyodbc, blender, calc

Is there already a pyodbc interface to connect to the (libreoffice) calc sheets. I can see there is one for micro$oft excel but not for the former.

I am building a data visualisation tool (very premature and scaffolding) for the blender 3D modelling tool
https://blenderartists.org/t/bui-blender-user-interface-scientific-visualisation/1244457
and would like to connect for now the calc to blender through pyodbc

possible?

KR
Hewi

Comment: Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14569434/2144390) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60663664/2144390).